# Web API Best Approach for returning HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I have a Web API project and right my methods always returns **HttpResponseMessage**.

So, if it works or fails I return:

**No errors:**

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"File was processed.");
```

**Any error or fail**

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "The file has no content or rows to process.");
```

When I return an object then I use:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
```

I would like to know how can I return to my HTML5 client a better encapsulated respose, so I can return more information about the transaction, etc.

I was thinking on creating a custom class that can encapsulate the HttpResponseMessage but also have more data.

Does anyone have implemented something similar?

Comment: You should not use any Content in a HttpStatusCode.NoContent.

Comment: Generally if you return a HttpActionResult with `HttpStatusCode.NoContent`, it will - surprise - return no content, even if you are passing in a string like in your case above. Can be a surprising bug. Like user BigTone 's answer below. 
This makes sense too according to the specification https://httpstatuses.com/204 `A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header fields because it cannot contain a message body.`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Although this is not directly answering the question, I wanted to provide some information I found usefull.
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/11/11/new-features-in-asp-net-web-api-2-part-i.aspx

The HttpResponseMessage has been more or less replaced with IHttpActionResult. It is much cleaner an easier to use.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
     Object obj = new Object();
     if (obj == null)
         return NotFound();
     return Ok(obj);
 }
```

Then you can encapsulate to create custom ones.
[How to set custom headers when using IHttpActionResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440307/how-to-set-custom-headers-when-using-ihttpactionresult)

I haven't found a need yet for implementing a custom result yet but when I do, I will be going this route.

Its probably very similar to do using the old one as well.

To expand further on this and provide a bit more info. You can also include messages with some of the requests. For instance.

```
return BadRequest("Custom Message Here");
```

You can't do this with many of the other ones but helps for common messages you want to send back.

Comment: Thanks to you, I will never use the dreaded HttpResponseMessage again

Comment: And if you're using MVC Core or whatever it's called today, the type you're looking for might be called `IActionResult`

Answer (score 8):

You can return an error response to provide more detail.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError("The file has no content or rows to process.") { { "CustomErrorCode", 42 } };
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myCustomError);
 }
```

Would return:

```
{ 
  "Message": "The file has no content or rows to process.", 
  "CustomErrorCode": 42 
}
```

More details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx

I also use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes to help me determine what http status code to return.

Answer (score 4):

One important note:  Don't put content in 204 responses!  Not only is it against the HTTP specification, but .NET can actually behave in unexpected manners if you do.

I mistakenly used `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, null);` and it led to a real headache; future requests from the same session would break due to having a `"null"` string value prepended to the response.  I guess .NET doesn't always do a full clear of the response object for API calls from the same session.

Comment: Generally if you return a HttpActionResult with `HttpStatusCode.NoContent`, it will - surprise - return no content, even if you are passing in content like in OP's case above. Can be a surprising bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning so don't what I'm about to say may be silly (or not).

Why not create a class/model for your APIResponse? Something like:

```
 public class APIResponse
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; } = true;
        public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
        public object Object { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you have a standard response easier to read and you can always add more information if you need to.